# Why was my solution converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion, support

Solution link:
https://superuser.com/q/359995/74026

For sub-10k users:

> If by converter you mean a cable adapter that converts between SATA and PATA, those are probably hit-or-miss as the two standards are very, very different.
>
> If you mean an add-in card which has SATA connectors, the questions are: Do you have a SATA power connector for the drive? And, did you install any windows drivers needed for the drive. If the SATA card uses the cheaper controllers, any drives connected to it may only be visible to the OS, not the BIOS.
>
> Personally, I'd recommend a minimally modified system for this setup. USB hard drive trays that accept SATA drives are relatively cheap. You'll be limited to USB speeds, but so long as it's USB2 it should be enough for local network streaming over all but the fastests networks. Then you're not dealing with adapters and connectors and specialised cards inside your system.

Question link: [Sata Drive in IDE Motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/359949/sata-drive-in-ide-motherboard)

I asked two clarifying questions, yes, but then also proposed a specific solution based on my own experience that dealt with all probable scenarios, including those covered by my questions.

Especially as my solution ended up being the most appropriate given the OPs eventual course of action, my solution ought not have been converted to a comment.

Some feedback as to why and whom would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider fully quoting the post in question for below 10k rep users

Comment: @DanielBeck its been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer was flagged as `not an answer`, and that was because of your two clarifying questions, so it was a comment/answer hybrid with a lot of guesswork in it...In reality, your post could have gone either way, as a comment or as an answer... I converted it to a comment, one because another user agreed that it wasn't an answer, and two, it was better as a comment.

Comment: Then please undelete it for the reasons specific above.

Comment: @music2myear it stays as a comment in its current form, it still reads like a big, long, comment.

Comment: Look at it now and reassess.

Comment: @music2myear a lot better, thank you! undeleted. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

More than three quarters, if not all of it, was guessing as to what they were asking in the question.

When an answer is more "if by this..." or "if you mean this..." then it's probably better as a comment, which are used to clarify the question.

Comment: You'll probably find many of the solutions are phrased that way. I deal with possible specifics that may not have been clarified and then go about answering them anyways. If the OP provides clarification that significantly changes what the answer may be, I then modify my answer to address the changes. May I please request the comment be converted back.